# uiScrollView performance with many uiLabels

Tags: performance, uiscrollview, uilabel

On the iphone...

I have a very long uiScrollView ( theScroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(460, 92000); ) and added to this I have about 200 uiLabels of different sizes, colours.

( It scrolls a little horizontally as well, as you can see with the 460 )

( I still have about 60 uiButtons to add as well! )

Scrolling at high speed is great but as it decelerates it jerks and judders a little too much.

The problem goes away if I set decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast; but this is too much for fast scrolling. As you can see I need to cover a fair old distance!

( I kind of need a fast deceleration rate when I'm doing gentle scrolling and the opposite for fast 'mad' scrolling. ** IF I went down the deceleration Rate route? ** )

I'm not sure if 'Lazy Loading' would help, I've just skim read a few Q&As on that?

thanks for any ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved a huge performance boost by removing uiLabels that are really long i.e you need to scroll for ages to see the whole label. By 'cutting' them up into smaller labels 'joined together', things run very smoothly.
I imagine the graphics card has to 'draw' the whole thing, or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem was solved by using CATiledLayer, give it a try